# vncserver remote session grey screen ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, unity, ssh, xfce, vnc

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 xenial. I am trying to set up a VNC remote session to log in from my laptop. VNC Server works and I am able to connect but all I get is a grey screen. I am using port forwarding via SSH to log in, then launch vncserver:

```
vncserver :7
```

My xstartup file is:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
xsetroot -solid "#DAB082"
x-terminal-emulator -geometry "80x24+10+10" -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager
```

Like I said, I can log in but all I get is grey screen. The log file

```
is:20/08/17 14:53:54 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
20/08/17 14:53:54 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
20/08/17 14:53:54 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
20/08/17 14:53:54 All Rights Reserved.
20/08/17 14:53:54 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
20/08/17 14:53:54 Desktop name 'X' (fiji:7)
20/08/17 14:53:54 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
20/08/17 14:53:54 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5907
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring

20/08/17 14:53:59 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
20/08/17 14:53:59 Using protocol version 3.8
20/08/17 14:54:01 Full-control authentication passed by 127.0.0.1
20/08/17 14:54:01 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
20/08/17 14:54:01 Using hextile encoding for client 127.0.0.1
20/08/17 14:54:01 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
20/08/17 14:54:01 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
20/08/17 14:54:01 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
20/08/17 14:54:01 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
20/08/17 14:54:01 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
20/08/17 14:54:01 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
20/08/17 14:54:01 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
20/08/17 14:54:01   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
20/08/17 14:54:01   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
20/08/17 14:54:01   no translation needed
20/08/17 14:54:09 Client 127.0.0.1 gone
20/08/17 14:54:09 Statistics:
20/08/17 14:54:09   key events received 0, pointer events 96
20/08/17 14:54:09   framebuffer updates 1, rectangles 2, bytes 400448
20/08/17 14:54:09     cursor shape updates 1, bytes 1068
20/08/17 14:54:09     hextile rectangles 1, bytes 399380
20/08/17 14:54:09   raw bytes equivalent 3145740, compression ratio 7.876559
```

I don't see any errors. If I use xfce4 via this xstartup, it works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
#unity &
```

The "unity &" was my effort to use unity over xfce4. I don't care about using xfce4 except that I'm having problems using notepadqq due to xkeyboard issue (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948081/notepadqq-xkeyboard-problem-with-xfce4-on-vncserver-remote)). Note that the xfce4 log has issues (e.g., Xlib: extension RANDR missing on display" but it still works.

I've looked at numerous incidents. I've tried vnc4server. Unity did work when I used the systemd version but I wanted to "improve" things by port forwarding more securely via SSH.